# Animation Frames

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

Can anyone help me on as to how frame animation is done using js or css. I am actually trying to achieve the same animation as [here](http://djump.in) .I am puzzled as to how the road animation works. Is it any plugin that does this or simply js and css

Comment: [link](http://djump.in)

Comment: It's a pre-animated graphics where each frame is merged to a spritesheet (I just peeked). You could also use SVG and canvas to do this. http://djump.in/assets/spritesheets/road-dde022c59294f8a4eb3bc6e544a18e55.png

Comment: it is done using the Kineograph plugin from [Here](https://github.com/epicagency/kineograph) (peeked deeper)

Comment: Or to sum: the plugin *drives* the sprite-sheet. How the animation itself was made is unclear (there are many options here...)

Comment: @K3N - I have used the plugin as you had mentioned and it works fine in chrome . In firefox and safari the problem is that when the page load for the first time, the script works , but from the second time onwards, it fails.

Comment: which part you are interesting in?

Comment: @mohammed moustafa- its about the animation of the track, the rest i have already acheived

Comment: you mean the dashed line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I did it as an image (SVG) format.
2. I animate it with pure HTML5 and CSS3 Animation.
3. With the class `.path` and `@keyframes`.
4. Unfortunately, Is not supported in IE and safari.

**Here is the code:**

```css
.line{
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

svg{
     display: block;
}

#svg path.path{
    stroke-dasharray: 3000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 4000;
    stroke-width: 2;
    
    -webkit-animation:lines 5s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation:lines 5s linear forwards;
    -ms-animation:lines 5s linear forwards;
    -0-animation:lines 5s linear forwards;
    animation: lines 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes lines {
form { stroke-dashoffset:4000;}
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }  
}

@-webkit-keyframes lines {
form { stroke-dashoffset:4000;}
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }  
}

@-moz-keyframes lines {
 form { stroke-dashoffset:4000;}
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0;}  
}

@-ms-keyframes lines {
 form { stroke-dashoffset:4000;}
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes lines {
 form { stroke-dashoffset:4000;}
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }

}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <svg id="svg" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="1000" id="Layer_1" style="opacity:1;" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 960 560" enable-background="new 0 0 960 560" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="path" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="1000" stroke-dasharray="11.9901,11.9901" d="M52.652,248.08
   c30.97,37.245,74.957,63.396,122.172,75.244c53.056,13.313,109.816,9.162,161.756-7.968
   c42.308-13.953,83.007-37.533,108.174-74.156c4.655-6.774,8.818-14.153,10.027-22.271c2.24-15.044-6.187-29.969-17.51-40.177
   c-28.483-25.679-73.116-26.422-108.534-11.588c-54.196,22.698-92.323,81.422-86.252,139.649
   c6.07,58.228,59.091,109.265,117.886,109.022c20.716-0.085,41.065-5.884,60.092-14.042c18.307-7.85,35.789-18.023,50.322-31.606
   c14.503-13.555,25.718-30.139,37.837-45.845c17.476-22.649,37.883-44.311,64.254-55.552c26.37-11.241,59.879-9.795,80.612,9.943
   c30.67,29.196,23.317,84.899,56.145,111.668c29.1,23.729,74.437,10.683,102.618-14.121c32.31-28.438,51.374-68.875,65.118-109.573
   c12.464-36.907,21.327-75.103,35.836-111.202" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[See the code in "Code Pen"](http://codepen.io/Mohammed_Moustafa/pen/yeRzpV/)

I hope that will help you and welcome to everyone if can edit my code to support it in IE and safari.

Comment: Awesome. This is what I exactly wanted. But , can you please tell me how did you generate such a smooth curve in svg? I plotted a similar kind of graph but it was very sharp at the curves .

Comment: Because I have touch screen so I used my hand and then saved it as an image then used any online website such http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html also you can use adobe illstrator. Since you like my answer please also do best answer too. thanks

Comment: ohhhh :(... i dont have that. but anyways, thanks a lot  :)